# rpc lib for blackberry / j2me ( json / xml / * )

Tags: json, blackberry, java-me, xml-rpc, rpc

I'm trying to setup an rpc server so that a blackberry mobile app can make calls to it. Thought of trying out json first.

I've setup a working server side impl using http://jsonrpcphp.org/ .

Couldn't find any direct libs for blackberry/j2me. [android-json-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/) looked interesting, but the blackberry SDK complains 
"The type java.net.URI cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" at this line

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serviceUri);
```

I'm using v4.1 of apache http core and client to make android-json-rpc work.

Looks like the URI class isn't bundled with the j2me/blackberry standard lib.

Is there a quick and dirty way to get rpc working on blackberry ? I don't mind xml or any thing else for the encoding, http is the transport I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry 6 has [built-in the JSON parser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/org/json/me/package-summary.html) and some [better APIs for making HTTP requests](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Code_sample_Parse_JSON_data_structure_1319797_11.jsp). Prior to that, though, you have to compile the JSON parser into your app and use the Java ME HttpConnection class to make and get the HTTP requests. So it depends what version you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting to < BB OS 6.0 devices. 
You can also use org.json.me lib in your app. 
Here is the sample named [Implementing JSON in your application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Implementing-JSON-in-your-application/ta-p/539659). It's very simple to use.

Good luck